# Function-App Proxy unable to pass through Certificate"X-ARR-ClientCert" to another Function-App's functions

Tags: azure, ssl-certificate, azure-functions, client-certificates

**My scenario:**

I want to use Function-App Proxy(use like APIM) to expose all my functions including those resides in other Function-App as well.

**Problem Statement**

I am unable to surpass the Certificate coming from client(caller) via proxy to backend functions.

Meanwhile, If the functions reside in the same function-app(which is used as a proxy) then the certificate passes to that function.

I am unable to find the exact reason, why it is not possible to surpass the certificate to backend functions resides in another Function-App?

[image]

Even I tried to send Certificate to Backend function by explicitly setting the header in the proxy backend url, but no luck.

**FunctionB certificate settings:**

[image]

I tried to return the Certificate details from the Function. [Following this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-configure-tls-mutual-auth).

**Please suggest, how can i achieve the solution to this scenario.**

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar question, but client certificates don't appear to be supported by Azure Function App proxies at this time.

"Proxy does not store any certs and does not validate any middle tier certs." - https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/1961